# Can I push events to Eloqua like Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools, eloqua

With Google Analytics I can push a custom event to the service with code like this in JavaScript:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']);
```

Is there a way to do this with Eloqua in conjunction with their JavaScript tracking code?

I found that I can do this:

```
_elq.trackEvent('http://example.com/documents/whitepaper.pdf')
```

But the example is specific to Outbound Link Tracking, and I'm not sure what the other parameters would be, if there are any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went on their website and checked the function, it has 3 parameters:

```
> _elq.trackEvent
   function (a,b,c){t(a,b,c)}
```

They all get passed to the URL:

```
> _elq.trackEvent('test111', 'test222', 'test333')
   undefined
   Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://s33.t.eloqua.com/visitor/v200/svrGP?pps=10&siteid=33&elq=test222&ref=test111&ref2=test333&ms=786"
```

This is just reverse engineering, they don't have any official documentation about it that I can find.

Comment: Do you know how that comes through inside Eloqua though?  I did try calling that function manually but didn't see any stats post to the associated contact in Eloqua.

Comment: You can pass parameters all day long but if eloqua has no way to report on it - passing additional parameters is useless.

Comment: That is why I specified it's just reverse engineering. Eloqua doesn't seem to support custom events, from what I see in their documentation and forums.

Comment: _elq.trackEvent is used for outbound link tracking. Not really for user events.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the [Eloqua Asynchronous Visitor Tracking Scripts](http://armorcastprod.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Eloqua-Async-Tracking-Scripts.pdf), Eloqua doesn't support Google Analytics-like event tracking.

You can track:

- Multiple Eloqua Instances
- Custom URLs/Referrers
- Outbound Link Tracking (what you referenced)
- Externally Hosted Forms
- Data Lookups
- Flash Content
- Strict Mode (opt-in by country/visitor)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the latest Oracle documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/eloqua-user/Help/EloquaAsynchronousTrackingScripts/Tasks/TrackingCustomURLs.htm

Eloqua reports reference page views so rather than custom events, you could use custom URL's to push any custom data. Two methods exposed are:

- _elq.trackEvent
- _elq.trackOutboundLink (references the above function)